# Creating a google drive folder on customers account

Tags: google-drive-api, hybrid-mobile-app

I am working on an application which requires the automatic creation of a folder on customer's Google Drive accounts as opposed to them creating this themselves.

I will have their permission to do so and won't have access to this folder. Ideally this folder would be encrypted but they could do this afterwards themselves.

Is it possible? And if  it, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using the REST API. See the section called **Creating a folder**.

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder